# Getting cover image from a mobi file

Tags: c#

I have a .mobi ebook file and I'm trying to extract the book cover image from it with C#.

http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/MOBI#MOBI_Header

I assumed the coveroffset contains the number of bytes from the beginning of the file, at which the cover image starts, but when I read it, I get only some random code, not image code. Not to mention there is no imagelength so I wouldn't even know, how much am I supposed read. So how can I find the image and get it out, if the header information is seemingly no help? I know it can be done, because when I put that mobi file into Calibre, it extracts and shows that cover image.

Comment: according to your link coveroffset should be added to  `108  0x6c  4  First Image index  First record number (starting with 0) that contains an image. Image records should be sequential. `  I think this may mean that there can be pages with images before the actual cover, e.g. adds or an inner sleeve, or that there is some text on the page before the cover image..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortunately, the link you provided has all the needed information, but the file format is described in a somewhat confusing way... I wrote the following quick & dirty code from this information, and it seems to do the job.

**This is not production quality code**, as there is almost no error/bound checking, but it should get you started.
Just call `CoverExtractor.ExtractCover` passing in a seekable stream.

```
public class CoverExtractor
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly BinaryReader _reader;

    private CoverExtractor(Stream mobiFile)
    {
        _stream = mobiFile;
        _reader = new BinaryReader(mobiFile);
    }

    public static Stream ExtractCover(Stream mobiFile)
    {
        if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You should rewrite this code if you intend to use it on a big-endian machine");

        return new CoverExtractor(mobiFile).Extract();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extract the cover image from a MOBI stram
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>null if there's no cover image</returns>
    private Stream Extract()
    {
        // A MOBI file is a Palm Database file containing MOBI-specific records.
        // A palm database file is a header, followed by a record list, followed by record data.

        // The first record (at index 0) contains the following concatenated data:
        //   - The PalmDOC header
        //   - The MOBI header
        //   - An optional EXTH header

        // Read the offset of the first record in the file
        var firstRecordOffset = ReadPdbRecordOffset(0);

        // Ignore the PalmDOC header, skip to the MOBI header at offset 16
        // and make sure it starts with the ASCII text "MOBI". If it does, we have a valid MOBI file.
        var mobiHeaderOffset = firstRecordOffset + 16;
        EnsureMagic(mobiHeaderOffset, "MOBI");

        // Read a couple useful values from the MOBI header
        var mobiHeaderLength = ReadUInt32(firstRecordOffset + 20);
        var firstImageRecordIndex = ReadUInt32(firstRecordOffset + 108);
        var exthFlags = ReadUInt32(firstRecordOffset + 128);

        // The "EXTH flags" bitfield indicates if there's an EXTH header.
        // If there's no EXTH header we won't be able to tell which image is the cover.
        if ((exthFlags & 0x40) == 0)
            return null; // There's no EXTH header

        // The EXTH header immediately follows the EXTH header, but as the MOBI header is of
        // variable length, we have to calculate the EXTH header offset.
        var exthOffset = mobiHeaderOffset + mobiHeaderLength;

        // Ensure the EXTH header starts with the ASCII string "EXTH" (just a validity check like before)
        EnsureMagic(exthOffset, "EXTH");

        // Read the "coveroffset" field value from the EXTH header
        var coverRecordOffset = ReadExthRecord(exthOffset, 201);

        // If the coveroffset field is not found, we assume there's no cover
        if (coverRecordOffset == null)
            return null; // No cover

        // Now, per the spec, the cover image is contained in a Palm Database record.
        // Image records are sequential in the MOBI file. These records start at index firstImageRecordIndex.
        // The cover image is one of these images. Its offset in the image records is coverRecordOffset.
        // With this info, we can deduce which record contains the cover image.
        var coverRecordIndex = firstImageRecordIndex + coverRecordOffset.Value;

        // Get the byte offset of the cover image
        var coverOffset = ReadPdbRecordOffset(coverRecordIndex);

        // Let's assume here the Palm Database records are indexed sequentially,
        // and are laid out sequentially as well, without any gap in between.
        // The PDB spec is not really explicit about that but it seems like a valid assumption.
        // Also, the MOBI spec says there's and end-of-file record, so the cover record won't be the last one.
        // Therefore, we can get the offset of the following record to deduce the image file size.
        var nextRecord = ReadPdbRecordOffset(coverRecordIndex + 1);

        // Now we know the start and end offsets of the cover image in the MOBI file, extract the data.
        _stream.Position = coverOffset;
        return new MemoryStream(_reader.ReadBytes((int)(nextRecord - coverOffset)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the byte offset in the file of the PDB record at the given index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recordIndex">The record index</param>
    private long ReadPdbRecordOffset(uint recordIndex)
    {
        // A Palm Database file is a header followed by a record info list.
        // The header is 78 bytes, and each record info is 8 bytes.
        return ReadUInt32(78 + 8 * recordIndex);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the given EXTH record value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exthHeaderOffset">Offset of the EXTH header</param>
    /// <param name="exthRecordType">Type of the record to read</param>
    private uint? ReadExthRecord(long exthHeaderOffset, int exthRecordType)
    {
        // The EXTH header contains records in no fixed order.
        // Each record has an type, a length and a value.

        // Read the total EXTH record count
        var exthRecordCount = ReadUInt32(exthHeaderOffset + 8);

        // Iterate over all the EXTH records until we find the one we're looking for
        for (var i = 0; i < exthRecordCount; ++i)
        {
            var recordType = ReadUInt32();

            // EXTH records have no fixed length, and the length provided in the record is for the whole record,
            // so we have to substract 8 bytes (the length of the "type" and "length" fields) in order to get the value length.
            var recordLength = ReadUInt32() - 8;

            // Check if we found the value record type we were looking for, and read its value
            if (recordType == exthRecordType)
                return ReadVariableLength(recordLength);

            // Throw the field value away and check the next field.
            // This is equivalent to _stream.Position += recordLength;
            _reader.ReadBytes((int)recordLength);
        }

        // We didn't find the field we were looking for
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads a byte, word or dword at the current position
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes">Number of bytes to read</param>
    private uint ReadVariableLength(uint bytes)
    {
        // EXTH record values do not have a fixed length, so just read whatever length is provided.

        switch (bytes)
        {
            case 1:
                return _reader.ReadByte();

            case 2:
                return ReadUInt16();

            case 4:
                return ReadUInt32();

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads a dword at the given offset
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="offset">Byte offset to read</param>
    private uint ReadUInt32(long offset)
    {
        _stream.Position = offset;
        return ReadUInt32();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads a word at the current offset
    /// </summary>
    private ushort ReadUInt16()
    {
        // Palm Database files are encoded in big-endian order, but BinaryReader reads everything in little-endian.
        return (ushort)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(_reader.ReadInt16());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads a dword at the current offset
    /// </summary>
    private uint ReadUInt32()
    {
        return (uint)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(_reader.ReadInt32());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for a magic identifier at the given offset.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="offset">Byte offset to check</param>
    /// <param name="magicString">Expected ASCII string at the given offset</param>
    private void EnsureMagic(long offset, string magicString)
    {
        // This function is made like that just for the sake of readability.
        // In real code, you should just read an uint32 and compare that to the expected number.

        _stream.Position = offset;
        if (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_reader.ReadBytes(magicString.Length)) != magicString)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid file format");
    }
}
```